# Does copying all cookie *.txt files from XP to Win7 work?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, firefox, cookies

I'm moving from Win Xp to Win 7.

There are 4500 cookie files in my C:\Documents and settings*UserName*\Cookies directory on XP, dating from 2 days ago back to 2010 (when I last cleaned out older ones).
There is an accompanying index.dat file of 3MB.
I have consistently been using FireFox for the last couple of years, so given the dates I assume they are cookies used by Firefox.

There are a few dozen cookie files in c:\Users*UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies and its subfolder Low on Win 7, all from the last few days.
There are accompanying container.dat files of 0 bytes in both directories.

I use Firefox and did a profile transfer (all settings) with [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/download.php). Mozbackup cannot transfer cookies.

I still have access through dual boot to my XP installation. FireFox is set to synchronize, but that does not have a 'cookies' option.

Can I copy the cookie files from the XP dir to the Win7 dir (which of the two?) and will they take effect there?

I may not copy all of them ;-)

Comment: Why not just try it? Or perhaps just try one or two.

Comment: That folder is not [where Firefox cookies are stored](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Cookies#Where_are_cookies_stored).

Comment: @and31415 Interesting - then what are all these recent *.txt files? Investigating...

Comment: @JanDoggen Those cookies were probably created by Internet Explorer or another program which used the [related Windows API functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: OK, I think I found it: My RSS reader is using the IE engine and I use that practically everyday as well. That's where those .txt cookie files must have come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an incorrect assumption in my question: "*given the dates [of the .txt files] I assume they are cookies used by Firefox.*"

It turns out my RSS reader ([RSSOwl](http://www.rssowl.org/)) is using the IE rendering engine and in all likelihood it was responsible for those cookies.

As user and31415 pointed out in the comments [FireFox cookies are stored in two SQLite databases in the profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Cookies#Where_are_cookies_stored).

So copying those cookies is useless for FireFox, but useful for RSSOwl.